# Advice on picking a data structure in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

Python and programming newbie here. Let's say I have these names... Brian, Chris, and Mike. I want to be able to store the names of the cards they've come across, whilst keeping track of the number of times they've seen that card. For example, Brian -->[Queen: 8, Ace: 3, Jack: 5], Chris --> [Queen: 4, Ace:2, Jack: 6] etc. I am not sure of what data structure to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a dict()

```
brian = {'Queen': 8, 'Ace': 3, 'Jack': 5}
chris = {'Queen': 4, 'Ace': 2, 'Jack': 6}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the response! Would i be able to increase the values anytime i see a similar card?

Comment: Yup... brian['Queen'] += 1

Answer (score 4):

The answer from **user590028** is correct, I'd like to add that perhaps you might want a 'parent' dictionary with nested dictionaries that would allow you to scale to more names

```
data = {
    'brian' : {'Queen': 8, 'Ace': 3, 'Jack': 5},
    'chris' : {'Queen': 4, 'Ace': 2, 'Jack': 6},
    'matt' : {'Queen': 0, 'Ace': 1, 'Jack': 3}
}
```

In this manner, we have a little more flexibility for calling the names

```
print data['brian']
print data['brian']['Queen']
```

And of course, as mentioned in the comment above, you can increment quite simply:

```
data['brian']['Queen'] += 1
```

Likewise, it should be easy to add some more names further down in the code

```
data['susan'] = {'Queen': 1, 'Ace': 23, 'Jack': 0}
```

Print data and see that 'susan' has been added. This should be a lot more scalable than creating a new container for each person.

Good luck on your Python journey!